# Created Jpanel with mutiple checkboxes and rendering to JTable cell causing issue

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpanel, tablecellrenderer

I created custom cell renderer which takes `value` parameter from method `getTableCellRendererComponent` and creates check boxes based on list of values which is `List` of `Integer`.

Issue is renderer is called multiple times when window is dragged or resized and panel is adding multiple times inside the cell of `JTable`, resulting in duplicate `JCheckBox`es.

**Renderer :**

```java
public class CheckBoxCellRenderer extends JPanel implements TableCellRenderer {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6142180432465856711L;
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

    public CheckBoxCellRenderer() {
        setOpaque(true);
    }
    
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        if(value!=null){
            Set<Integer> intValues = (Set<Integer>) value;  
            for(Integer intvalue : intValues){
                panel.add(new JCheckBox(intvalue.toString()));
            }
        }
    //  panel.add(this);
    //  table.setRowHeight(row, this.getPreferredSize().height);
        panel.revalidate();
        panel.repaint();
        return panel;
    }
}
```

**cell editor:**

```
class CheckBoxCellEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7910769369831526953L;
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {     
        //table.setRowHeight(25);
        //table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        if(value!=null){
            Set<Integer> intValues = (Set<Integer>) value;  
            for(Integer intvalue : intValues){
                panel.add(new JCheckBox(intvalue.toString()));
            }
        }
         
        //table.setRowHeight(row, panel.getPreferredSize().height);
        return panel;
    }
}
```

**Main panel :**
(`infoTable` is `ModelTable`)

```
infoTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setCellRenderer(new CheckBoxCellRenderer());
infoTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setCellEditor(new CheckBoxCellEditor());
infoTable.addNewRows(modelList);
```

Comment: I advise you to not create the component you want to render in your getTableCellRendererComponent merhod. Instead have it already created in the class and just set the values in the method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be aware that usually only one instance of `TableCellRenderer` is created and it is used to render every cell in the `JTable`.

Every time the `JTable` needs to be redrawn, method `getTableCellRendererComponent` will be called. Obviously when you drag or resize the `JTable`, it needs to be redrawn.

A simple solution would be to first [removeAll](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Container.html#removeAll()) the `JCheckBox`es from the `JPanel` before adding the new ones.

Note that the default [layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for class `JPanel` is `FlowLayout` so no need to explicitly set it.

```java
public class CheckBoxCellRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6142180432465856711L;
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
                                                   Object value,
                                                   boolean isSelected,
                                                   boolean hasFocus,
                                                   int row,
                                                   int column) {
        if(value!=null){
            panel.removeAll();
            Set<Integer> intValues = (Set<Integer>) value;  
            for(Integer intvalue : intValues){
                panel.add(new JCheckBox(intvalue.toString()));
            }
        }
        return panel;
    }
}
```